# How can I access a higher level $_ pipeline variable from a nested pipeline?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that will look at a directory of Parent VHD files and then evaluate which VMs are using those parent VHDs.

I have the mechanics of it working but I am running into an issue where I really need to reference a automatic pipeline variable ($_) from the context of a nested pipeline

The sudo code would be something like:

```
For each File in Files
Iterate over all VMs that have differencing disks
and return all the VMs that have a disk whose parent disk is File
```

Here is the actual powershell code I have implemented so far to do this:

```
$NAVParentFiles = get-childitem '\\hypervc2n2\c$\ClusterStorage\Volume1\ParentVHDs' | where {$_.Name -notLike "*diff*"} | select name
$NAVParentFiles | % { Get-VM | where {$_.VirtualHardDisks | where {$_.VHDType -eq "Differencing" -and ($_.ParentDisk.Location | split-path -leaf) -like <$_ from the outer for each loop goes here> } }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide me on how to elegantly access an outer pipeline variable from a nested pipeline.

Comment: Sometimes nestead `foreach`es is more readable than nested pipelines.

Comment: Similar question with similar solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26715634/11942268

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can assign the `$_` to a variable and use that:

```
 1..10 | %{ $a = $_; 1..10 | %{ write-host $a} }
```

Anyway, consider refactoring your script. It is too nested. Concentrate on readability. It is not always necessary to pipe, you can use a `foreach` loop if that helps improve readability.

Comment: That did the trick =). I am looking at refactoring the code as you suggested and possibly going to nested foreach loops where it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have that command, but maybe the -pipelinevariable common parameter can be of use here.

```
Get-VM -PipelineVariable vm | Get-VHD |
  Select-Object @{n='Name'; e={$vm.name}}, path, parentpath
```