# Variables in nested Foreach-Object and Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering how to work with nested Forach-Object, Where-Object and other Cmdlets in Powershell. For example this code:

```
$obj1 | Foreach-Object { 
    $obj2 | Where-Object { $_ .... }
}
```

So in the code block of Foreach-Object I use the elements of `$obj1` as `$_`. But the same happenn in the code block of Where-Object with `$obj2`. So how can I access both objects elements in the Where-Object code block? I would have to do `$_.Arg1 -eq $_.Arg1` but this makes no sense.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

afaik, You'll need to keep a reference to the outer loop by putting it in a local variable.

```
$obj1 | Foreach-Object { 
    $myobj1 = $_
    $obj2 | Where-Object { $_ .... }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Another way do address this is with a slighty different foreach

```
ForEach($item in $obj1){
    $obj | Where-Object{$_.arg -eq $item.arg}
}
```

Still boils down to [about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx). `$_` is always a reference to the current scope. As you must know `($_.Arg1 -eq $_.Arg1)` would just be refering to itself.

Comment: I know about a "real" foreach loop but I'm ssearching a solution for exactly this problem, because this happens in deferent situations. It could be without Foreach-Object too.

Comment: @Michael then you have to save the variable so that it is accessible to the other scopes like Lieven and I are suggesting.

Comment: @Matt, does `$_` have a parent-object reference that can be used in these situations?  Something like `$itemArray | % { $_.childArray | % { $_.Parent.ParentProperty }}`

Answer (score 2):

If the match is simple enough, you can get rid of the inner code block and avoid a local variable.

```
$obj1 | Foreach-Object { 
    $obj2 | Where property -eq $_.property
}
```

e.g:

```
$array = ("zoom", "explorer", "notreal")
$array | foreach { get-process | where ProcessName -EQ $_ | Out-Host }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use scopes nowdays, e.g. a foreach inside a foreach can be accessed with `$_` and the parent foreach can be accessed within the child loop using `$script:_`