# Foreach and array variables in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, import

I am importing a CSV and recycling that site based on the values in the CSV. The csv is dynamically buildup based on the alerts we receive. 
When I try the following code I receive an values printed and errors

```
import-csv d:\emscripts\recy\recycle.txt -Header "site","IP","Log" | foreach {
    $_.IP
    $_.site
    $appPool = Get-WmiObject -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate  -ComputerName $_.IP -namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2"  -class IIsApplicationPool | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/AppPools/$($_.site)" }
    $appPool.Recycle()
    }
```

*192.168.100.182
Testsite1
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:5
+     $appPool.Recycle()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

192.168.100.131
testsite2
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:5
+     $appPool.Recycle()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull*

You can see that the values are printed but it is failing to get anything into the $appPool.

I have changed it to the following and it is working as expected.

```
    $RecyleSites  = import-csv recycle.txt -Header "site","IP","Log" 
foreach ($site in $RecyleSites)  {
    $site.IP
    $site.site
    $appPool = Get-WmiObject -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate  -ComputerName $site.IP -namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2"  -class IIsApplicationPool | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/AppPools/$($site.site)" }
    $appPool.Recycle()
    }
```

I am trying understand what I am doing wrong in the first set of code ?

Comment: Add code to verify that you are really getting back the WMI object that you think you are.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and I was getting null for $appPool. But the second set of similar code is working. Only difference is I am taking that values in to a array and in the first set I am trying to pass it as I read. I think it is not passing  the values of _.site  or  $_.IP.

Comment: I just tested with ForEach-Object also. No, it is not working, the same result. with the foreach also it is printing the values but not going into Get-WmiObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this piece of code from your original sample contains your problem:

```
Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/AppPools/$($_.site)
```

`$_.site` isn't in scope any more because `$_` now represents the current object in the `Where-Object` "loop". When you printed `$_.site` as the first line of the foreach loop, `$_` still represented the current item in the `$RecycleSite` list.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean. but how can I use the first loop and the second loop in this case. Any idea ?

Comment: Your corrected version of the code looks OK. Anywhere you can you should explicitly reference the object you want (ie. $site.IP vs $_.IP). The reason to do that is exactly what your question pointed out, that "$_" represents different objects depending where it gets used.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scope issue here for sure. You need to save the variable `$_.Site` for later use.

```powershell
$site = $_.site
$appPool = Get-WmiObject -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate  -ComputerName $_.IP -namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2"  -class IIsApplicationPool | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/AppPools/$site" }
$appPool.Recycle()
```

`$_` always refers to the object in [scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx). Saving variables outside of that scope for use is a common practice.

Your `ForEach` construct is doing just that by saving the assigning the variable in each pass to `$site`

Comment: That's right, which is essentially what he has done by changing to the "foreach($site in $RecycleSites)" loop. But yes, if you want to use the format of the first code snippet, you'd have to do the above.

Comment: Many thanks, I just got this after checking the question [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237251/how-can-i-access-a-higher-level-pipeline-variable-from-a-nested-pipeline and tested it.

Comment: I am unable to make both answers  as answer.. So I am keeping the first answer told me about the issue as answer.  Thanks