# Output as side effect in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I pipe `Select-Object` and want output from the selects as I go.

I could use $_, variables or loops but hope for a nicer implementation,
one that just outputs to the console as a side effect and continues, like

```
Get-Whatever | Pipe-Out Name, Phone | Do-Whatever Surname, Address | ...
```

---

My example string is

```
Get-VM  | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD | Select-Object path, parentpath | Format-List
```

which gives me roughly the output

```
Path                           ParentPath
----                           ----------
C:\Users\...\Ubuntu...avhdx    C:\Users\...\Ubuntu.vhdx
C:\Users\...\Foss...avhdx      C:\Users\...\Foxx..vhdx
```

where I want the `Name` from `Get-Vm` too. (`Get-VM | Select-Object Name`).

```
Name      Path                           ParentPath
----      ----                           ----------
Ubuntu    C:\Users\...\Ubuntu...avhdx    C:\Users\...\Ubuntu.vhdx
Foss      C:\Users\...\Foss...avhdx      C:\Users\...\Foxx..vhdx
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access a higher level $\_ pipeline variable from a nested pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237251/how-can-i-access-a-higher-level-pipeline-variable-from-a-nested-pipeline)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Not exactly. I was hoping to avoid using `$_`, variables and loops.

Comment: I think that's the same question.  You're wondering if there's a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have that command, but there is a -PipelineVariable common parameter.

```powershell
get-vm -pipelinevariable vm | get-vhd |
  select-object @{n='name'; e={$vm.name}}, path, parentpath
```

Comment: My result is this: `get-vm -PipelineVariable vm | select VMId | Get-VHD | select {$vm.Name}, Path, ParentPath`

Comment: If you want the name of the property to be "$vm.name", that's up to you.